# can not find entity using seam managed persistence context

Tags: authentication, seam, seam2, amazon-iam, jboss-seam

I'm trying to change the authentication approach in my seam application. I currently use a login form to authenticate. In the future, I'd like to delegate the authentication to another layer that will rewrite every request with a specific HTTP header containing the username of authenticated user.

I'm facing a weird problem: when using login page to authenticate, I'm able to extract the user through the entityManager. But when I query the entityManager using the information off the header, I'm unable to find the user. The entityManager behave like the user does not exist.

I already tried two approaches:

- Creating a fake login page which triggers the authentication process
- Creating a servlet which gets the request and starts the
  authentication process

Both times, the entityManager fails to return me any user.

I read a lot about how seam manages the persistence context, but I didn't find a single explanation which make this issue clear. Do you have any ideas? suggestions? or even guesses?

the code which uses the entityManager is the following:

```
@Name("userService")
@AutoCreate
public class UserService {
    @Logger
    private Log logger;

    @In
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public User getUser(String email) {
            try {
                return entityManager
                        .createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u where u.email=:email",
                                User.class).setParameter("email", email.trim())
                        .getSingleResult();
            } catch (NoResultException e) {
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```

The configuration for persistence context is:

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context startup="false" scope="stateless"
        auto-create="true" name="entityManager" persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/EntityManagerFactory" />
```

I created an empty fake login page which executes a page action (authentication) in which i get the request user header as the following:

```
@Name("applicationAuthenticator")
public class ApplicationAuthenticator {
    @Logger
    private Log log;

    @In
    private Identity identity;
    @In
    private Credentials credentials;
    @In(required=true)
    private UserService userService;

@Begin
    public void login() throws LoginException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String userName=request.getHeader("user");
        identity.unAuthenticate();
        credentials.setUsername(userName);
        credentials.setPassword("fake");
        identity.acceptExternallyAuthenticatedPrincipal(new SimplePrincipal(credentials.getUsername()));
        User user=userService.getUserByEmail(credentials.getUsername());
        identity.authenticate();
        identity.quietLogin();
    }
}
```

Thx in advance  :-)

Comment: Can you post some code? Especially the bit that uses the entity manager

Comment: It seems that a seam interceptor(hibernate security interceptor as i guess) is prohibiting the access to the datasource through the entityManager.do you have any idea on how to disable or bypass just the hibernate security interceptor?

Comment: Have you checked that the string is actually being taken from the header? If so is the query actually executing? Also it may be obvious but is your UserService class restricted at all?

Comment: indeed yes i checked the string taken from the header,it's the same sent through the request and used in the query.The UserService is not restricted at all.it's a bit weired but when i call applicationAuthenticator.login using the login submit button the query gets the user correctly which is not the case using the http GET request.

Comment: have you tried checking what SQL hibernate is executing (if anything)? also try dropping the hibernate logging level down to see whats going on

Comment: I drop down hibernate logging level, the query is being correctly transmitted and have the right parameter but the result set have no rows (0 rows), how is this possible? what can be the source for hibernate loader(org.hibernate.loader.Loader) to not get the row from the db?

Comment: Ok so enable sql logging (in persistance.xml) and check the exact SQL that hibernate is generating and compare with the working 'form' login query, I bet there is a slight difference in there, whitespace? or case sensitive?

Comment: I've enabled sql logging (in persistence.xml) and compared the two queries, weirdly it's the exact same query.i'm wondering how is that possible? is it possible that hibernate executed the query when being totally disconnected from the db?

Comment: I dont think thats possible, if the query is returning no results (without showing any warnings/exceptions) there MUST be a difference in the queries being executed. Are you using Seam Security? If so maybe you you should use RunAsOperation to execute the query

Comment: Affirmative it's the same query that's been executed. Indeed, yes i'm using Seam Security, does that affect querying the db? i used RunAsOperation with adding admin role but i'm having the same behaviour.
Scanning the hibernate log i noticed that when i getting the user correctly(using the login form) there are two queries being executed (the first to get the user the second to get the role) which is not the case using http GET request.Does Seam Security has a hand in that?

Answer (score 0):

Thx @DaveB for your reply, the code which uses the entityManager is the following:

```
public User getUser(String email) {
        try {
            return entityManager
                    .createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u where u.email=:email",
                            User.class).setParameter("email", email.trim())
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The configuration for persistence context is:

```
<persistence:managed-persistence-context startup="false" scope="stateless"
        auto-create="true" name="entityManager" persistence-unit-jndi-name="java:/EntityManagerFactory" />
```

I created an empty fake login page which executes a page action (authentication) in which i get the request user header as the following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String userName = request.getHeader("user");
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that the query above doesnt give any results when it is invoked as a page action, but it does work when it is invoked from a standard login form...? Can you post the whole backing bean / class, specifically how are you getting your entityManager instance.

Comment: btw. you should add this extra detail to the question not as an answer

Comment: Thx DaveB for your quick reply :), i updated the question with more code details.what i'm saying is that the query does work using the login form (the submit button in the form executes the page action), but when i send a http GET request (with the user header) to a page action(applicationAuthenticator.login) the query doesn't work(userService.getUser returns null).